# PHP getting empty output with SQL Server Stored Procedure call

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a stored procedure on MS SQL Server, but i get an empty result. The stored procedure takes the user id as input parameter, and outputs the name, address, city, state and zip code of the user.

Here is the execution query of Stored Procedure on SQL Server Management Studio:

```
USE [MYDB]
GO
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @Name char(60),
        @Address char(60),
        @City char(30),
        @State char(3),
        @Zip char(10)

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spAddressByUserID]
        @UserID = N'AB1234',
        @Name = @Name OUTPUT,
        @Address = @Addr1 OUTPUT,
        @City = @City OUTPUT,
        @State = @State OUTPUT,
        @Zip = @Zip OUTPUT

SELECT  @Name as N'@Name',
        @Address as N'@Address',
        @City as N'@City',
        @State as N'@State',
        @Zip as N'@Zip'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

So far, i have tried the following code:

```
<?php
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $host, $connectionInfo);
$user_id = 'AB1234';
$myparams['UserID'] = $user_id;

$procedure_params = array(
    array(&$myparams['UserID'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$myparams['Name'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$myparams['Address'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$myparams['City'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$myparams['State'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$myparams['Zip'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
);

$sql = "EXEC spAddressByUserID @UserID = ?, @Name = '', @Address = '', @City = '', @State = '', @Zip = ''";

$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $procedure_params);

if( !$stmt ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt)){
  while($res = sqlsrv_next_result($stmt)){
    print_r($res); // Gives Empty Output
  }
}
else{
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

I think all my syntax is correct. But i get empty output. Not sure what i am doing wrong.

**EDIT:**

I have modified the array parameters of query like this, with no success:

```
$procedure_params = array(
    array(&$myparams['UserID'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, 'SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING'),
    array(&$myparams['Name'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, 'SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING'),
    array(&$myparams['Address'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, 'SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING'),
    array(&$myparams['City'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, 'SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING'),
    array(&$myparams['State'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, 'SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING'),
    array(&$myparams['Zip'], SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, 'SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to run the proc in SQL Management studio successfully? It also looks like you are missing some placeholders in your SQL in PHP. Only one `?` in the query. Perhaps this is better?

```
$sql = "EXEC spAddressByUserID @UserID = ?, @Name = '?', @Address = '?', @City = '?', @State = '?', @Zip = '?'";
```

I'm not very familiar with stored procs of this kind, but with parameterized placeholders in prepared statements, you need to specify all the placeholders, in the correct order. From what you posted, it seems to me that you are not adding the placeholders in all the places it needs to go, and perhaps that is why you are not getting the output back?

Comment: I am able to run the Proc in SQL Management studio successfully. And i also mentioned all placeholders ('?') in my query as suggested, but still i get the empty output.

Comment: @shasikanth I just noticed that the params are marked as SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, not SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT.

Comment: I specified the params as SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT. But then i got this error message: An invalid PHP type was specified as an output parameter. DateTime objects, NULL values, and streams cannot be specified as output parameters.

Comment: @shasikanth I'm not sure which driver versions you are using, or if its even fixed, but there seems to have been a bug with PHP not being able to allocate enough memory for its variables receiving the output. Please try to add the PHP-type to the params list: `array(&$myparams["Zip"],SQLSRV_PARAMETER_OUT, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING)`.

Comment: @shasikanth You could also try to pre-initialize the array with dummy data to be overwritten.

Comment: @shasikanth See an example doing this here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php#115353

Comment: I am using the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. I also tried adding the  PHP-type to the params list: 'SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING' and pre-initializing the values. Still no luck.

Comment: @shasikanth please update the question with the current code. Just add it as an edit below the original question.

Comment: It turned out that i don't have required permissions to call the stored procedure. So i had to execute sql server query, instead of calling stored procedure. Finally the query worked out this way:
**SELECT [Name], Address, City, State, Zip FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'AB1234';**